# Does $m^*(E)=m(E\cap A)+m^*(E\cap A^c)$ always true?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Caratheodory says that $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ is measurable if $$m^*(A)=m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E^c\cap A)$$
for all $A\subset \mathbb R^d$. To me a more natural way would have been to define it as : $E$ is measurable if
$$m^*(E)=m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E\cap A^c)$$
for all $A\subset \mathbb R^d$. But, maybe the equality hold for all $A\subset \mathbb R^d$, even if $E$ is not measurable, that's why it wouldn't be a good definition. What do you think ?

Comment: Your first equation should say
$$m^*(A)=m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E^c \cap A).$$

Comment: @kccu: I corrected it, thanks,

Comment: Let $E = [0,1]$. Clearly $E$ is measurable but for certain nonmeasurable sets $A$ it is possible that $m^*(E \cap A) = m^*(E \cap A^c) = 1$.